# Do not define components during render React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

i am getting this error while writing TypeScript React Native code

Do not define components during render. React will see a new component type on every render and destroy the entire subtree’s DOM nodes and state (https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#elements-of-different-types). Instead, move this component definition out of the parent component “BottomTabNavigator” and pass data as props. If you want to allow component creation in props, set allowAsProps option to true.eslintreact/no-unstable-nested-components

file .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: '@react-native',
  rules: {
    'react-native/no-inline-styles': 0,
  },
};
```

eslint warning

Do not define components during render. React will see a new component type on every render and destroy the entire subtree’s DOM nodes and state (https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#elements-of-different-types). Instead, move this component definition out of the parent component “BottomTabNavigator” and pass data as props. If you want to allow component creation in props, set allowAsProps option to true.eslintreact/no-unstable-nested-components
(property) TextStyle.color?: ColorValue | undefined

```
 options={{
              tabBarIcon: ({focused}: any) => {
                return (
                  <View
                    style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <Icon
                      name={icon}
                      style={{color: focused ? colors.green : colors.gray}}
                    />
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        fontSize: 12,
                        color: focused ? colors.green : colors.gray,
                      }}>
                      {title}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                );
              },
            }}
```

full code

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import CourseScreen from '../screens/CourseScreen';
import BlogScreen from '../screens/BlogScreen';
import SearchScreen from '../screens/SearchScreen';
import MenuScreen from '../screens/MenuScreen';
import {colors} from '../constants/colors';

const tabs = [
  {
    title: 'Home',
    name: 'HomeScreen',
    screen: HomeScreen,
    icon: 'home',
  },
  {
    title: 'Course',
    name: 'CourseScreen',
    screen: CourseScreen,
    icon: 'book',
  },
  {
    title: 'Blog',
    name: 'BlogScreen',
    screen: BlogScreen,
    icon: 'edit',
  },
  {
    title: 'Search',
    name: 'SearchScreen',
    screen: SearchScreen,
    icon: 'search1',
  },
  {
    title: 'Menu',
    name: 'MenuScreen',
    screen: MenuScreen,
    icon: 'setting',
  },
];

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const BottomTabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="HomeScreen"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
      }}>
      {tabs.map(({title, name, screen, icon}: any, index: any) => {
        return (
          <Tab.Screen
            key={index}
            name={name}
            component={screen}
            options={{
              tabBarIcon: ({focused}: any) => {
                return (
                  <View
                    style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <Icon
                      name={icon}
                      style={{color: focused ? colors.green : colors.gray}}
                    />
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        fontSize: 12,
                        color: focused ? colors.green : colors.gray,
                      }}>
                      {title}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                );
              },
            }}
          />
        );
      })}
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default BottomTabNavigator;
```

Answer (score 1):

my fix

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import CourseScreen from '../screens/CourseScreen';
import BlogScreen from '../screens/BlogScreen';
import SearchScreen from '../screens/SearchScreen';
import MenuScreen from '../screens/MenuScreen';
import {colors} from '../constants/colors';

const tabs = [
  {
    title: 'Home',
    name: 'HomeScreen',
    screen: HomeScreen,
    icon: 'home',
  },
  {
    title: 'Course',
    name: 'CourseScreen',
    screen: CourseScreen,
    icon: 'book',
  },
  {
    title: 'Blog',
    name: 'BlogScreen',
    screen: BlogScreen,
    icon: 'edit',
  },
  {
    title: 'Search',
    name: 'SearchScreen',
    screen: SearchScreen,
    icon: 'search1',
  },
  {
    title: 'Menu',
    name: 'MenuScreen',
    screen: MenuScreen,
    icon: 'setting',
  },
];

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const renderTabIcon = ({icon, focused, title}: any) => (
  <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
    <Icon
      name={icon}
      size={20}
      style={{color: focused ? colors.green : colors.gray}}
    />
    <Text
      style={{
        fontSize: 10,
        color: focused ? colors.green : colors.gray,
      }}>
      {title}
    </Text>
  </View>
);

const BottomTabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="HomeScreen"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
      }}>
      {tabs.map(({title, name, screen, icon}, index) => (
        <Tab.Screen
          key={index}
          name={name}
          component={screen}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({focused}: any) =>
              renderTabIcon({icon, focused, title}),
          }}
        />
      ))}
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default BottomTabNavigator;
```